# How to merge the display of multiple row in the DataTable server side

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

Ihave 3 tables in phpmyadmin. disease_table, medicine_table, disease_medicine_table.

Case: The disease can have multiple medicines that's why I made the third table named disease_medicine table that linked the disease table and medicine table.

My problem is how to get all the records of the disease.

I'm using codeigniter framework

My desired result in datable is:

- id - disease_name - medicines
- 1 - toothache - med1,med2,med3,med4
- 2 - headache - med4,med8,med2,med5

and this is my **current result in png**

### [datatable result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvolg.png)

Or do you have a better idea to fix my problem?

This is my disease table

- id(int11)
- disease_name(varchar255)

This my medicine table

- id(int11)
- med_name(varchar255)
- dosage_strength(varchar255)
- price(decimal65,2)

This my disease_medicine table

- id(int11)
- disease_id(int11)
- medicine_id(int11)
- dosage(varchar255)
- quantity(int64)

Im going to display the data in DataTable server side and this is my code

**Ajax controller**

```
public function get_diseases_for_table() {
    $data = [];

    if(($ajax_data = $this->input->get()) && $this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        extract($ajax_data);
        $data = [
            'draw' => $draw,
            'recordsTotal' => $this->diseases->get_diseases_records_total(),
            'recordsFiltered' => $this->diseases->get_diseases_records_filtered($ajax_data)
        ];

        $data['data'] = $this->diseases->get_diseases($ajax_data);
    }
    $this->view = FALSE;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_diseases_records_total() {
    $sql = 'SELECT d.id, d.disease_name, m.med_name, d.created_at ';
    $sql .= 'FROM diseases d ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN diseases_medicines dm ON d.id = dm.disease_id ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN medicines m ON dm.medicine_id = m.id ';

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->num_rows();
}

public function get_diseases_records_filtered($data) {
    extract($data);
    $params = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT d.id, d.disease_name, m.med_name, d.created_at ';
    $sql .= 'FROM diseases d ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN diseases_medicines dm ON d.id = dm.disease_id ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN medicines m ON dm.medicine_id = m.id ';
    $sql .= 'WHERE 1 ';

    if(!empty($search['value'])){
        $sql .= 'AND (d.id = ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR d.disease_name LIKE ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR m.med_name LIKE ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR d.created_at LIKE ?) ';
    }

    if(!empty($search['value'])){
        $params[] = $search['value'];
        $params[] = $search['value'];
        $params[] = $search['value'];
        $params[] = $search['value'];
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);

    return $query->num_rows();
}

public function get_diseases($data, $details = false) {
    extract($data);
    $params = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT d.id, d.disease_name, m.med_name, d.created_at ';
    $sql .= 'FROM diseases d ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN diseases_medicines dm ON d.id = dm.disease_id ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN medicines m ON dm.medicine_id = m.id ';
    $sql .= 'WHERE 1 ';

    if(!empty($search['value'])){
        $sql .= 'AND (d.id = ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR d.disease_name LIKE ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR m.med_name LIKE ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR d.created_at LIKE ?) ';
    }

    if(isset($order)){
        $sql .= 'ORDER BY ' . $columns[$order[0]['column']]['data'] . ' ' . strtoupper($order[0]['dir']) . ' ';//$order[0]['column']
    }
    $sql .= 'LIMIT ?, ?';

    if(!empty($search['value'])){
        $params[] = $search['value'];
        $params[] = '%' . $search['value'] . '%';
        $params[] = '%' . $search['value'] . '%';
        $params[] = '%' . $search['value'] . '%';
    }

    $params[] = (int)$start;
    $params[] = (int)$length;


    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);

    return ( $query->num_rows() ) ? $query->result() : FALSE;
}
```

**Script**

```
$('#disease_list').DataTable({
'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'responsive': true,
    'ajax': 'dis/diseases',
    'deferRender': true,
    'order': [[0, 'asc']],
    'columns': [
        { 'data': 'id', 'sClass': 'text-center' },
        { 'data': 'disease_name' },
        { 'data': 'med_name' },
        { 'data': 'created_at' },
        { 'data': 'options' },
    ],
    'columnDefs': [
        {
            'data': 'options',
            'targets': -1,
            'sortable': false,
            'render' : function ( data, type, row ) {
                var html = '<div class="text-center"> \
                                <div class="btn-group"> \
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle btn-hc_app" data-toggle="dropdown"> \
                                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i> \
                                    </button> \
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu"  style="padding: 0 0 7px 0"> \
                                        <li> \
                                            <span class="dropdown-title text-center">Action Bar</span> \
                                        </li> \
                                        <li> \
                                            <a href="#" title="Edit" data-id="' + row.id + '"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw fg-green"></i> Edit Entry</a> \
                                        </li> \
                                        <li> \
                                            <a href="#" title="Delete" title="Edit" data-id="' + row.id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw fg-red"></i> Delete Entry</a> \
                                        </li> \
                                    </ul> \
                                </div> \
                            </div>';
                return html;
            }
        }
    ],
    'language': {
        "processing": '<div class="processing-wrapper"> \
                            <div><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Fetching ... Please wait...</div> \
                        </div>',
        'emptyTable': 'No medicine type(s) available in the database!',
        'zeroRecords': 'No medicine type(s) found!',
        "infoFiltered": ""
    }
});
```

Comment: Not clear at all what is or isn't working which makes the question *"how do I get all the records"* far too vague. Narrow down where you are specifically having problems. Also suggest reviewing [ask]

Comment: I updated my question @charlietfl

Comment: All I see is you changed a few words in the title but that isn't a definitive problem statement. Especially when you re showing both client side and server side code to us

Comment: Where is `$search['value']` populated and is it an Object? An Array? If not, you're feeding the same value into each parameter ofor the SQL Query in `get_diseases_records_filtered($data)` I would expect something like `$params[] = $search['value'][0]; $params[] = $search['value'][1];` etc....

Comment: @MichaelAmaleona a sample of the resulting data would also be helpful. Still trying to understand what data you have and what you're trying to get. I wonder if you may need a Union statement versus a Join. Since your question is not clear, about what you're trying to get from what tables, we're struggling to understand the issue.